# MySQL column with conditional value

Tags: mysql, case, conditional-statements

I have this basic SQL sentence:

```
SELECT p.s1,pr.s1 FROM `prop` p LEFT OUTER JOIN prom pr ON pr.id = p.prom
```

My intention is to have a column with the value of `pr.s1` if it's not null, and `p.s1` in other case. It's very simple, but i don't know how to do it correctly.

Any idea will be very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IFNULL`:

```
SELECT IFNULL(pr.s1, p.s1) AS s1
FROM `prop` p
LEFT OUTER JOIN prom pr
    ON pr.id = p.prom
```

Comment: its a simple change

Answer (score 2):

To round things out, you could also use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(pr.s1, p.s1)
FROM prop p
LEFT OUTER JOIN prom pr
    ON pr.id = p.prom
```

One nice thing about using `COALESCE()` over `IFNULL()` is that the former can take more than two parameters.  So if, for example, you had two backup columns in case of a `NULL` value you could do:

```
SELECT COALESCE(pr.s1, p.s1, p.someOtherCol)
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ifnull

```
 SELECT p.s1, ifnull(pr.s1, p.s1) 
 FROM `prop` p 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN prom pr ON pr.id = p.prom
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COALESCE()` :

```
SELECT p.s1,COALESCE(pr.s1,p.s1) 
FROM `prop` p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN prom pr
 ON pr.id = p.prom
```

Although you may have two identical columns, so I think you meant :

```
SELECT COALESCE(pr.s1,p.s1) as s1
FROM ...
```